# CSS div transition; on mouseover, but not on mouse-out?

Tags: css, html, transition

I am trying to make an image which has a div which fades in on mouse over, but then fades out again as the mouse moves away. I want the div though to come to about 50% of the image and have some text in it

I have managed to sort out the fading in, but as soon as the mouse leaves, it doesn't gracefully fade out, it just disappears...

Here is my current code:

CSS

```
body { font-family: 'Jolly Lodger', cursive; width:800px; height:600px; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#container { width:50%; height:100%; background-color:#0000ff; margin:0px; padding:0px; position:relative; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; }
popup { opacity:0; -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-out; }
popup:hover { opacity:0.6; }
pop { opacity:0; -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-out; }
pop:hover { opacity:1; }
#picture { max-height:100%; margin-left: -100%; } 
#container:hover popup { position:absolute; top:0; height:25%; width:100%; background-color:#00ff00; display:block; opacity: 0.6; padding:30px 0px 0px 0px; }
#container:hover pop { position:absolute; top:0; height:25%; width:100%; opacity: 1; display:block; padding:30px 0px 0px 0px; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Caneel_Bay_Free_Roaming_Wild_Donkeys.jpg" id="picture" />
<popup>&nbsp</popup>
<pop><p><font size="7">I fade!</font></p> <p>Fade in!</p></pop>
</div>
```

JSFiddle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jmKFv/

I have tried to put the -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-out within different tags, as that's what I've seen advised by other people on here, but it only seems to want to work there. If in another space, it doesn't animate at all

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be simple but not really. Scanning it thoroughly let me know that you did it in a very wrong way. The reason your `pop` is disappeared right after leaving the mouse is not because its opacity is not animated/transitioned, it's because its position jumps out of view (and you also set the `overflow:hidden` for the container). Another problem is your `popup` has background of `transparent` initially and the opacity of 0, after leaving the mouse only the opacity is animated but the background is switched back (from `green`) to `transparent` immediately, that's why it's disappeared without any backwards transition.

To fix the problem you should setup all the properties in the normal state of your elements, in the hover state, you just need to change the property you want to animate/apply transition (that is the `opacity` property), here is the fixed code:

```
popup {  opacity:0; height:25%; width:100%; 
         background-color:#00ff00; 
         position:absolute; left:0; top:0;
         display:block; padding:30px 0px 0px 0px; z-index:1;
         -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-out; 
}
popup:hover { opacity:0.6; }
pop { opacity:0; height:25%; width:100%;
      position:absolute; left:0; top:0;
      display:block; padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 4s; }
pop:hover { opacity:1; }
#picture { max-height:100%; margin-left: -100%; } 
#container:hover popup { opacity: 0.6; } /* change only the opacity here */
#container:hover pop { opacity: 1; }    /* change only the opacity here */
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/jmKFv/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help and explaining the issue, I see and understand where I went wrong, I got confused about what the end result was so wrote it all a bit backwards. Thanks again for clearing it up

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your CSS rules: you're assigning the position, height, width, display, etc. to `popup` and `pop` when the mouse is over the `#container`, but the only thing you want to change when the mouse is over the `#container` is the opacity. So when the mouse leaves the container your `popup` and `pop` are moving because their position is changing and you can't see the transition.

To fix it, you need to assign every property but opacity to `popup` and `pop` when the mouse isn't over the `#container`:

```
#container popup { position:absolute; top:0; height:25%; width:100%; background-color:#00ff00; display:block;  padding:30px 0px 0px 0px; }
#container pop { position:absolute; top:0; height:25%; width:100%;  display:block; padding:30px 0px 0px 0px; }
#container:hover popup { opacity: 0.6; }
#container:hover pop {opacity: 1; }
```

See it in action here: http://jsbin.com/wacorevi/1/edit

By the way, why are you using `popup` and `pop` tags instead of standard HTML tags?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explaining, very helpful :) I used nonstandard because I thought it would be better to have a section with no predefined values to it so I could manipulate it more, but looking at what went wrong I can see how and that I should be using div instead